# NoClassDefFoundError with EJB classloader

Tags: ejb, classloader

I'm getting a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/company/comum/entity/api/MyEntity" on deploying my .ear. This "MyEntity" is on "ejb-commo"n module and is a interface that JPA entities implement. The module "ejb-testapp" has some JPA entities which implements "MyEntity".

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <version>6</version>
        <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
        <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib/</defaultJavaBundleDir>
        <modules>                        
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb-common</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>                                          
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb-testapp</artifactId>
             </ejbModule>   
             <webModule>
                <groupId>br.com.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>web-testapp</artifactId>
                <contextRoot>/desktop</contextRoot>
             </webModule>     
         </modules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I've checked the dependencies in the poms and it's all right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about in eclipse (m2e-wtp) then try right clicking on the project and doing export -> EAR and see what comes out. I did this and noticed the jars were being output into the root of the EAR (m2e-wtp was effectively ignoring <defaultJavaBundleDir>).

I changed it to use <defaultLibBundleDir> instead (maven have changed the name of the setting to this, but kept defaultJavaBundleDir valid for backwards compatibility) and it worked as expected.